# Check if user is signing up or signing in in azure AD B2C user flow

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-b2c

I'm implementing a ***Sign up and sign in*** user flow in my React JS app using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-azure-adb2c).

I've successfully registered a user and signin registered user in my app. But I wanted to know how to check if the user is signing up or signing in?

I've checked the access token in https://jwt.ms/ but there is no difference between the token returned after signing up and token returned after signing in.

How can I check if the user has signed up or signed in to the app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `newUser` Application claim in **Sign up and sign in** user flow.

You can select it on B2C_1_signupsignin -> Application claims.

[image]

After that, if you sign up, the token will include this claim `"newUser": true`. If you sign in, the claim `newUser` won't be returned.